# Lazy range class in R

Tags: r, range, lazy-evaluation

In R, ranges are immediately evaluated into vectors:

```r
> 1:3
[1] 1 2 3
```

Is there an idiomatic way to construct ranges without evaluating them into lists, or must I define it myself?

```r
setClass(
  "Range",
  representation(
    start = "numeric",
    stop = "numeric"
  )
)

Range <- function(start, stop) {
  new("Range", start = start, stop = stop)
}

setMethod("show", "Range", function(object) {
  cat(paste0(object@start, ":", object@stop, "\n"))
})
```

Comment: Is there a reason you want to do this?  What is your actual goal?

Comment: To store information about a range in a single structure.  Many languages have [these types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range).  Typically these structures will have methods on them, for example checking if a value is in that range, or if a range is enclosed in another, etc.  It would be convenient not to have to define such methods myself.

Answer (score 3):

There is an [iterators package on CRAN](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=iterators), which might be what you're looking for.  However, while it has a "counting iterator" `icount()`, there's not an obvious way to make it start anywhere other than 0 ... you could hack it by messing with the internal environment, but it would be better to construct your own range iterator (which would be basically be rolling it yourself again).

The other thing to be aware of is that sequences constructed with `:` are already stored as ALTREP ("alternative representation") objects, so they're much smaller than you think:

```r
vec <- 1:1e10
lobstr::obj_size(vec)
680 B
```

(however, if you try to print this object it will print the first `getOption("max.print")` elements - it won't resist evaluating itself ...)

---

To be slightly pedantic, I would say that ranges *aren't* "immediately evaluated into vectors", thanks to ALTREP. However, they *are* evaluated if you print them ...